# how to variable pass mail function in php

Tags: php, html, css

I am new to php and i want solution for variable pass in mail function
I am using this way to variable pass mail function but getting issue Code:

```
<?php
require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

function Send_Mail($to,$subject,$body,$cc = "",$bcc = "")
{
    $mail = new PHPMailer;
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->SMTPDebug = false;
    $mail->Username = 'xyz@gmail.com'; // Your Gmail Address
    $mail->Password = '123456'; // Your Gmail Password 
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
    $mail->Port = 465;
    $mail->From = 'xyz@gmail.com'; // From Email Address
    $mail->FromName = 'gfgg'; // From Name
    $mail->addAddress($to);
    $mail->addReplyTo('xyz@gmail.com', 'dfg'); // Same as From Email and From Name.
    $mail->WordWrap = 50;
    $mail->isHTML(true);
    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    $mail->Body    = $body;
    if(!$mail->send()) {
       return array('status' => false, 'message' => $mail->ErrorInfo);
    }
    return array('status' => true, 'message' => 'Email Sent Successfully');
}

if (isset($_REQUEST['submit']))
{
   $name=$_POST['name'];
   $email=$_POST['email'];
   $contact=$_POST['contact'];
   echo $name, $email, $contact;
  $result = Send_Mail('$name','$email','$contact');

}
```

pls give me soltution
    ?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Send_Mail function requires minimum 3 parameters, which are `$to`, `$subject` and `$body`in this order.
So first of all you are calling your parameters within strings

```
$result = Send_Mail('$name','$email','$contact');
```

and in the wrong order.

You should probably try this

```
$result = Send_Mail($email, "Subject", "Message");
```

You will have to define $subject and $message variables and replace them with "Subject" and "Message"

Comment: $result = Send_Mail("$email", "Subject", "Message"); already try this code

Comment: No, not "$email", you have to type in $email without " ". Otherwise it can be seen as a string with the content "$email" and not your actual email adress.

Comment: how to all variable pass in $body variable mail function in php

Comment: It depends on your form. If you have a textarea with the name "body", you would just do it like `$body = $_POST['body'];`.

Comment: i  have to  add body part 5 to 6 variable pass

Comment: Without knowing your form, i can't answer you. How about reading this about String Operators on [PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)

Comment: my form filed name,email,city,fresher,information,subject,choose file add in body part

Answer (score 0):

Try with -

```
echo "$name, $email, $contact";
$result = Send_Mail($name,$email,$contact);
```

Comment: What issue you are getting?

Comment: pls give me other solution

Comment: mail function not getting variable value i static value pass mail function that time mail send